# AWS Lambda diff between code in editor and deployed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The title really says it all, I haven't been able to find any information on it, so I'm assuming it's not possible without external source control but is there any way to see what the difference between the lambda code currently deployed and what changes are waiting to be deployed?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to compare versions of your function (at a code level comparison) is by using external source control options like git.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was the case but I was hoping there was something I was missing